# NSDate in iOS6 not the same as in iOS5

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios6, nsdate

I had this code working for iOS5, but I just teste

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSString *strDate = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",now];
```

Does anyone know easy solution of rewriting this. The format of the date should be 
dd mm yyyy

Comment: The code you posted results in the `description` method being called on the `NSDate` object. The output of the `description` method is only meant for debugging and the output can change over time (as you have seen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this one , Definitely will get Proper solution:


NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];//as per your requirement

NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"]; //as per your requirement

NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];

NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:now];
NSString *theTime = [timeFormat stringFromDate:now];

NSLog(@"theDate:%@ "theTime:%@" , theDate, theTime);
```

Answer (score 7):

The correct way to format a date as a string is to use an [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/). You can set the style to something appropriate for the user’s current locale with the [`-setDateStyle:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDateFormatter/setDateStyle%3a) method, or set the format to a particular string with [`-setDateFormat:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDateFormatter/setDateFormat%3a).